# how do i print out in c++ and linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
class twoSumClass{
    public:
        vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target){
           vector<int> result;
           unordered_map<int,int> hm;
           for(int index = 0; index < nums.size(); index++){
            int findVal = target - nums[index];
            if(hm.count(findVal) > 0 && hm[findVal] != index){
                result.push_back(index);
                result.push_back(hm[findVal]);
                return result;
            }
            else{
                hm.insert(make_pair(nums[index], index));
            }
           }
           return result;
        }
};
void Print(vector<int>& v){
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout << v[i] <<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    vector<int> items = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int trgt = 2;
    twoSumClass myTest;
    std::vector<int> res = myTest.twoSum(items, trgt);
    Print(res);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my simple code, I am trying run this code in linux terminal as: g++ test1.cpp -o test1, and then run: ./test1
however, terminal does not print anything.
how do i change code? BTW, the purpose of code is similar with leetcode question #1 add two sum.

Comment: Why do you ask about printing out, but don't guess about the empty vector `res`?

Comment: `if(hm.count(findVal) > 0 && hm[findVal] != index)` is never true so the vector is empty.

Comment: This would be the correct way to output the values in a `std::vector<int>`. But I don't think your function is adding anything to your `res` vector.

Comment: It should be obvious that it is not a print issue if you do basic debugging. That is, run your program in a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Here is a version with extra print statements that may help show you why you never put anything in the vector: https://onlinegdb.com/HJgJ-qhrL

Comment: Cool, you are right. it's never add anything to res

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    vector<int> items = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int trgt = 2;
    ...
}
```

You want to find out 2 integers in *vector items* and their sum equals *trgt*.
There is no answer in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.
So no print is the correct answer.

Advise you to read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you are right, I need really pay attention to that. thanks a lot!